# Windows 7 issue

Tags: windows

I downloaded a cracked version of something but then I deleted it, and now it downloaded 2 Chinese things. Both of them seem like a browser. I've deleted them countless times but they still exist. I have this thing called processor hacker. I went in it tried to terminate both of them. All it says is "access denied", unable to terminate", and "need administration permission" and it still won't work.

Comment: It's time to reinstall Windows

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid you have to reinstall Windows. Not just to fix this momentarily bug you are facing, but more the risk you are exposing your system to unwanted people.

Never install software that doesn't come from a trusted source or has problems with certificate validation or so. That program might have installed a lot of malware you can't see now and you really don't what to linger around.

Comment: This should be one of first advices given during computer license courses!